Vue access components
I want to trigger the update() function of kursAktiv.vue when I press the button "Kursanlegen" in kursAnlegen.vue ! Here are the kursAnlegen button and function:
 <kursverwalter v-model:value="props_kursverwalter_anlegen" v-bind:mitglieder="mitglieder"
 v-bind:mitgliedsarten="mitgliedsarten" v-bind:platzkategorien="platzkategorien">
            <div align="left" class="form-group">
                 <div class="btn-toolbar">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="kursAnlegen"
                         :disabled="!kursAnlegenAllowed" style="margin-left: 23px;">Kurs anlegen</button>
               </div>
             </div>
         </kursverwalter>

and
kursAnlegen: async function () {
            if (this.props_kursverwalter_anlegen.anmeldung_end < this.props_kursverwalter_anlegen.anmeldung_start) {
                this.requestResponse = "Das Ende des Anmeldezeitraums befindet sich vor dem Beginn des Anmeldezeitraums!"
                document.getElementById('dropdownErklaerung').scrollIntoView();
                return
            }
            if (this.props_kursverwalter_anlegen.laufzeit_end < this.props_kursverwalter_anlegen.laufzeit_start) {
                this.requestResponse = "Das Ende der Laufzeit des Kurses befindet sich vor dem Beginn der Laufzeit des Kurses!"
                document.getElementById('dropdownErklaerung').scrollIntoView();
                return
            }

            try {

                await apiRequest("post", "kursverwaltung/kurs", this.props_kursverwalter_anlegen);
                this.requestResponse = "Kurs erfolgreich angelegt."

            } catch (ex) {

                console.log(ex)
                this.requestResponse = "Kursname ist bereits vergeben oder nicht alle erforderlichen Felder wurden ausgefüllt."

            }
            document.getElementById('dropdownErklaerung').scrollIntoView();


        }


and here is the kursAktiv hmtl code until the props and data def.:
<template>
  <box_content>

    <h2 id="scrollToTopAktiv"><strong>Aktive Kurse</strong>

      <div class="" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 110px; position: absolute; top: 16px; color: #909090">
        <a class="additional-icon" id="dropdownErklaerung" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
          style="color: #909090"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>

        <div class="fragezeichenErklaerung dropdown-menu pull-right" style="margin-right: -150px"
          aria-labelledby="dropdownErklaerung">
          In diesem Menü können Sie die aktiven Kurse einsehen.
        </div>
      </div>

      <template v-if="kurse && kurse.length > 0">
        <div class="pull-right selectobenrechts" style="margin-top: -10px; max-width: 368px;">
          <select v-model="selected_kurs_id" class="form-control inline" data-width="150px"
            style="z-index:0 !important; display: inline-block;;" @change="updateSelection">
            <option disabled value="-1">Bitte Kurs wählen</option>

            <option v-for="kurs in kurse" :key="kurs.id" :value="kurs.id">
              {{ kurs.name }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </template>

    </h2>

    <p></p>

    <template v-if="requestResponse != ''">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; padding-top: 6px;">x</button> {{ requestResponse }}
      </div>
    </template>

    <template v-if="kurse && kurse.length > 0">
      <template v-if="selected_kurs_id != -1">

        <kursverwalter  v-model:value="selected_kurs" :mitglieder="mitglieder" v-bind:mitgliedsarten="mitgliedsarten"
          v-bind:platzkategorien="platzkategorien" >
          <div align="left" class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="kursUpdaten" :disabled="!kursUpdatenAllowed">Kurs
                speichern</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="kursLoeschen">Kurs löschen</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </kursverwalter>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <center>
          <h2>Bitte wählen Sie einen Kurs aus.</h2>
        </center>
      </template>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <center>
        <h2>Es sind keine aktiven Kurse vorhanden.</h2>
      </center>
    </template>

  </box_content>
</template>
  
<script>


import { apiRequest } from "../../services/api.js"

import box_content from "../../components/box_content.vue"

import kursverwalter from "../../components/kursverwaltung/kursverwalter.vue"
import { datumermitteln } from "../../services/service_scheduler"
import kursAnlegen from "./kursAnlegen.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    box_content, kursverwalter,
    kursAnlegen
},
  props: {
    neuKurs:0,
    mitglieder: [],
    mitgliedsarten: [],
    platzkategorien: [],
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      kurse: null,
      selected_kurs_id: -1,
      selected_kurs: {},
      requestResponse: "",
    }
  },

Thanks in advance! :D
I worked with v-bin and importing the functions but it showed that there is no such funktion...

I think that a smaller [repro] with only the necessary code is welcome here and might help you narrow down the issue.
